# Unity - Texture2D.Loadimage resulting in MemoryWarning

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d, ipad-mini, memory-warning

I currently work on a 2D project on Unity (for mobiles/tablets), where I download a few heavy pictures by using `UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url)`, which I then store using `File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, webRequest.downloadHandler.data)`.

Later in the project, I need to show the downloaded picture on a RawImage element. To avoid blocking the app I read the bytes via FileStream on a separate Thread, which works well.

But when I call (from the main thread) `((Texture2D) myRawImage.texture).LoadImage(loadedBytes)`, my Profiler shows a huge peak, and if most devices handle it correctly, on iPad Mini I often get a MemoryWarning at this very point. Which, when repeated, leads to the app being forced close by iOS.

For info, the downloaded image's size vary depending on the device asking it. We initially intended to display 2048x1536 pictures that way on iPad Mini, but we were getting MemoryWarning on each display. We're now using 750x1334, but we still get MemoryWarning from time to time.

My question then is : is there a better way to do the "LoadImage" step ? I believe that the conversion from `byte[]` to `Texture2D` is where my memory problem lies, but I didn't find any workaround to this.

Or eventually: Is there a better way to download/store the image? If the image was in the app's resources from the beginning, I don't seem to have any trouble displaying it on the same device. Maybe there is a way to download the texture while applying it the same **compression** algorithm that assets receive when building an app ?

Comment: This is a known issue in Unity. No fix yet. Go native with C++, libpng/jpeg, OpenGL and Thread( on the C++ side) and you'll be able to fix it yourself. There is no other way to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it saddens me to read this.
Could you please just explain what is the known issue exactly? (Handling MemoryWarnings? Not being able to compress downloaded textures? Something else?)

Comment: *"But when I call (from the main thread) ((Texture2D) myRawImage.texture).LoadImage(loadedBytes), my Profiler shows a huge peak,"* `Texture2D.LoadImage` function to cause a spikes. The spike is more noticeable on mobile devices. The spike can cause a momentary freeze and the fix is what I mentioned above. That's what I meant.

Comment: As for your memory issue, simply use `UnityWebRequest.Get` instead of `UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture` then use `Texture2D.LoadImage` to load the image into Texture2D.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Texture2D.Compress()` after loading the texture compresses the texture by at least 90%.

[Reference](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/93117)